# angular how to check form length

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to know if we can get the length or check if the mat input field has input or not empty. In the code below in HTML I have an input field which ask for email address.

I tried modelForm.get('emailAddress').length but I think it is wrong , any idea?

I only want to show the element on HTML 2 below if there is input in the email address field.

#t.st

```
 this.modelForm = this._createModelForm();

  private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
```

#html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Username or Email</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="email" autocomplete="emailAddress" formControlName="emailAddress">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('emailAddress').hasError('required')">
                                Email is required.
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

#html 2

```
<div fxLayout="row" *ngIf="modelForm.get('emailAddress').length > 0 ">
                <span id="text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Enter user's information (*)</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could do:

```
<div fxLayout="row" *ngIf="modelForm.get('emailAddress').value.length > 0 ">
    <span id="text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Enter user's information (*)</span>
</div>
```

`modelForm.get('emailAddress')` will return you a `FormControl`. To get the value you'll have to use the `value` property on the control

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: is `emailAddress` part of the `modelForm`?

Comment: could you share a repro on stackblitz?

Comment: Hi @C_Ogoo , can you help me to implement this component Sir ? I am trying to find similar thing on angular material component but cant find one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249527/angular-material-alert-component

Answer (score 1):

`(modelForm.get('emailAddress').value || "").length`

Or with typescript

`modelForm.get('emailAddress').value?.length || 0`

If the field is empty it can be null, which caused the error you commented about above. These options cover the error appropriately